# Running embedded H2 database with mvn jetty:run

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, h2

I've been trying to figure out how to run an embedded database through a profile and be able to run REST calls through postman. 
This is what I have so far:

```
<profile>
        <id>developRest</id>
        <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                    <version>${h2.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <driver>org.h2.Driver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:h2:mem:test</url>
                <username>sa</username>
                <password>sa</password>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>my-execution</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                        <srcFiles>
                            <srcFile>src/test/resources/table-ddl.sql</srcFile>
                            <srcFile>src/test/resources/insert-into-table.sql</srcFile>
                        </srcFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webApp>
                        <descriptor>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty.xml</descriptor>
                    </webApp>
                    <stopKey></stopKey>
                    <stopPort></stopPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </build>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <version>${h2.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
```

I've played around with phases but nothing really seems to stick. When I run this with mvn sql:execute@my-execution jetty:run, the servlet runs but once I call a rest method I get

`Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (my-execution) on project myProject: The parameters 'driver', 'url' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute are missing or invalid`

What am I missing that will get the driver and url to be valid? Thanks for your help.

Update: Used `mvn -PdevelopRest sql:execute@my-execution jetty:run` to get rid of the driver and url error but still stuck with:

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "myTable" not found; SQL statement:
```

When calling a GET from postman. Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it hard to believe that you get a Maven error when you call a REST method (`Failed to execute goal ...`).

That aside, I think your real problem is this: you are using H2 as an in-memory database, that means that it's available as long as your application runs. When your application goes away, so does your database.

In the context of Maven, where you have multiple plugins executing, the database does not outlive the execution of a single plugin. Your `my-execution` instantiates an in-memory database, which then goes away. The `jetty-maven-plugin` creates its own in-memory database, which then does not have any of the DDL/SQL that went into the previous one.

There is probably a number of ways to fix this, like these:

1. Don't use an in-memory database, rather have H2 write out files, e.g. [`jdbc:h2:/data/test`](http://h2database.com/html/cheatSheet.html), or, since you're using Maven: `jdbc:h2:${project.build.directory}/data/test`
2. Don't initialize the database using the `sql-maven-plugin`, but directly inside the application. You could do that:

   1. With some custom code, that you only put on the test classpath
   2. By adding the DDL/SQL to the connection string of the application ("[Execute SQL on Connection](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#execute_sql_on_connection)"), like so:

      ```
      jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=runscript from '~/table-ddl.sql'\\;runscript from '~/insert-into-table.sql'";
      ```

H2 is an awesome database. Good luck!

Comment: I did end up not using an in-memory database. I was really hoping I could (since it is so convenient!). But you're right in that it doesn't persist which I hoped I could figure out. Thanks for your advice. The Maven error pops up due to trying to connect to the database in the rest call. But since I switched over to using the H2 server and connect to that I no longer get that error since the db persists. Thanks again!